# temperature conversion using functions c#

Tags: c#, console

hello i have looked around and couldnt find a c# console application that uses functions to convert a temperature. i have almost completed the program but for some reason the celcius temperature does not show up if someone could help lead me to the answer that would be great!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace temp_conversion
{
class tempConversion
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double far, cel;
        far = GetTemp("Far");
       cel= Celcius(far);
        DisplayResults(far,cel);


    }//end of main method

    public static double GetTemp(string temp)
    {
        string inputValue;
        double far;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Fahrenheith Temp");
        inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
        far = double.Parse(inputValue);
        return far;
    }

    static double Celcius(double far)
    {

        double cel = 5.0 / 9.0 * (far - 32);
        return cel;

    }

    public static void DisplayResults (double far , double cel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fahrenhieith temp {0:N2}", far);
        Console.WriteLine("C    ", cel);
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
    }
}//end of class
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't show up". Your code looks like it should at least *display*. Please include more details when asking for debugging help.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("C     {0:N2}", cel);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the {0:N2} like you have for far in the writeline for cel.

e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine("Celcius Temp {0:N2}", cel);
```

Comment: gosh i should have known. thanks for the fresh eyes!

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
Console.WriteLine("C    ", cel);
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine("C   {0:N2} ", cel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

> Console.WriteLine("C       {0:0.00}", cel);